# Dependency Resolution Is Failing The Build Process on Circle CI : androidx.annotation

Tags: scala, sbt, circleci

My Circle CI build is failing because of this error:

```scala
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /home/circleci/.ivy2/local/androidx.annotation/annotation/1.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/androidx/annotation/annotation/1.1.0/annotation-1.1.0.pom
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:246)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$34(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:215)
```

Locally my project builds w/o an issue so not sure why the Circle CI build doesn't work. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.annotation/annotation/1.1.0, this artifact is only available from the Google repository.

You probably have this added as a resolver on your local machine?

```
resolvers += "google" at "https://maven.google.com/"
```